# Duda sobre la funcionalidad del try & except

Tags: python, try-catch

Buenas tengo una duda con respecto a la funcionalidad de este código simple que hice:

```
while True:
    try:
        c_i = int(input("Introduzca la cédula del paciente: "))
        name = input("Introduzca el nombre del paciente: ")
        last_name = input("Introduzca el apellido del paciente: ")
        phone = int(input("Introduzca el teléfono del paciente: "))
        medical_appointment = input("Introduzca la razón de consulta del paciente: ")
        break
    except:
        print("Dato inválido, por favor introduza nuevamente los datos")
```

Es un ejercicio que quiero realizar a base de esta funcionalidad para hacer una validación más rápida.
Mi duda es ¿este try&except permite que no se puedan introducir números en "name" o en "last_name"? Creo que no pero realmente no estoy seguro, quisiera que solo se puedan introducir números "c_i" y "phone" y que no puedan haber números en "name" y "last_name", y en la ultima que se pueda colocar cualquier dato.

Comment: Buen día, el código que muestras no impide que name y last_name reciban números. Lo que buscas hacer se llama validación una forma común de hacerlo es usando expresiones regulares (Regex, del inglés Regular Expressions)

Comment: como un while condicional o usando un if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hace `try` es marcar un bloque de código para indicar que "podría producirse una excepción durante su ejecución". Si se produjera la excepción, se ejecutaría lo que pongas en el bloque `except`.

Pero solo ciertas instrucciones pueden producir excepción. Por ejemplo, `input()` no causará ninguna excepción teclee lo que teclee el usuario, pues admite cualquier cadena. En cambio `int()` sí podrá producir una excepción si la cadena que le pasas no es interpretable como entero. Así que tu `except` se ejecutará sólo si alguno de los `int()` falla. En definitiva, no te sirve para evitar que se metan números en otros campos.

En general no debe usarse `try/except` para validación, sino cuando puede ocurrir algún otro tipo de error imprevisto.

Para validar la entrada es mejor utilizar funciones de procesamiento de cadenas, de las que python tiene muchas que pueden ayudarte aquí. Por ejmplo:

- `str.isdigit()` te retorna `True` si todos los caracteres de la cadena son dígitos
- `str.isalpha()` te retorna `True` si todos los caracteres de la cadena son letras (pero te dará `False` si aparece cualquier cosa que no sea letra, como por ejemplo un espacio, un punto, etc. por lo que probablemente no te sirva aquí)
- `re.match()` permite usar expresiones regulares que es un mecanismo muy potente (y complejo) para especificar *patrones* que debe o no debe cumplir tu cadena. Por ejemplo, es fácil ver si una cadena contiene un dígito con el patrón adecuado: `re.match(r".*\d.*", cadena)`

Usando este tipo de cosas podemos escribir funciones de apoyo para tu problema. Puedes escribir una función que espere un número y que no deje introducir otra cosa (forzando una y otra vez al usuario a teclear algo hasta que teclee un número válido). Esto necesitará un bucle del que sólo se sale cuando se teclea lo que se espera. Puedes implementarlo por ejemplo así:

```py
def input_numero(prompt):
  while True:   # Bucle infinito, se sale con break
    cadena = input(prompt)
    if cadena.isdigit():  # Salimos si es un número
      break
    # En caso contrario repetimos el bucle, con un mensaje de error
    print("Debe introducir un número")
  # Al salir del bucle retornamos el número, ya convertido a entero
  return int(cadena)
```

Esto lo usarías por ejemplo así:

```py
c_i = input_numero("Introduzca la cédula del paciente: ")
```

Análogamente escribirías una función `input_no_numero()` que solo permita cadenas que no contengan números. Para esto sería interesante tener una función similar a `.isdigit()` pero que nos dijera cuando *no hay* números. Python no trae esta implementada pero podemos escribir una:

```py
def no_contiene_numeros(cadena):
  for caracter in cadena:
     if caracter.isdigit():
        return False          # Hemos encontrado un número, es Falso que no contenga
  # Hemos acabado de procesar la cadena sin encontrar números
  return True
```

Con ayuda de esta función y copiando la estructura de `input_numero()` no debería serte difícil implementar `input_no_numero()`.

Con ayuda de este par de funciones tu código principal quedaría así:

```py
c_i = input_numero("Introduzca la cédula del paciente: ")
name = input_no_numero("Introduzca el nombre del paciente: ")
last_name = input_no_numero("Introduzca el apellido del paciente: ")
phone = input_numero("Introduzca el teléfono del paciente: ")
medical_appointment = input("Introduzca la razón de consulta del paciente: ")
```

**Nota:** Este código es preferible al que tenías inicialmente porque valida *cada dato* cuando es introducido. Si el usuario mete correctamente `c_i`, `name` y `last_name` pero en `phone` mete algo que no es un número, se le volverá a pedir el teléfono y no todo lo anterior como ocurría con tu código.

**Nota2:** Quizás `phone` no debería ser un entero, pues quizás pueda incluir prefijos internacionales y por tanto símbolos como +, - o paréntesis. Podrías escribir otra función `input_phone()` que valide si la cadena introducida tiene algún carácter no válido, y que retorne finalmente la cadena si era válida.

Answer (score 1):

El patrón estándar para pedir y validar un dato numérico es:

```
while True:
    try:
        valor = int(input(msg))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Valor incorrecto.")
```

Primero pides el valor e intentas convertirlo a entero con `int`. Si eso falla, se produce una excepción que es atrapada por `except`.

Como todo está en un ciclo infinito, la única manera de salir es vía `break`. La única manera de llegar al `break` es que el ingreso sea efectivamente entero.

Podemos poner lo anterior en una función que recibe el mensaje y no retorna hasta tener el valor pedido:

```
def ingresar_valor_int(msg: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            valor = int(input(msg))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Valor incorrecto.")

    return valor
```

y usarla así:

```
x = ingresar_valor_int("Ingrese edad: ")
print(x)
```

produce:

```
Ingrese edad: asdf
Valor incorrecto.
Ingrese edad: 4
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```